# How to keep order of POST parameters in Django test client?

Tags: python, django, rest, unit-testing, paypal

I am writing a unit test for a Django view and I have this in my unit test:

```
data_from_paypal_other_id = {'client_id': '1', 'receiver_email': 'badguy@example.com', 'amount': '1.5'}
self.client.post(reverse('paypal_ipn_listener'), data=data_from_paypal_other_id)
```

The problem is PayPal requires me to send a POST request with parameters in a specific order. [Don't ask me why, see this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/).

The Django test client I see the parameters in messed up order:

```
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="receiver_email"

badguy@example.com
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="amount"

1.5
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

1
--BoUnDaRyStRiNg--
```

Note that `receiver_email` jumped before `client_id`.

My question is how do I force Django test client to keep the order of arguments?

Comment: Try to use OderdedDict https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of `dict` should do the trick. Make sure you initialize it with a *sequence* and not the original dictionary, e.g:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data_from_paypal_other_id = OrderedDict([
    ('client_id', '1'), ('receiver_email', 'badguy@example.com'),
    ('amount', '1.5')])
```